# Appending a string to XSL value after XSLT

Tags: xslt, concatenation

XSL file:

```
<xsl:attribute name="id">                          
    <xsl:value-of select="$text/FieldName"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

XML data:

```
<FieldName>
   meLikeStackOverflow
</FieldName>
```

after XSLT...

```
<id>meLikeStackOverflow</id>
```

How can i edit the XSL files such that after XSLT, it will look like this:

```
<id>meListStackOverflow_LBL</id>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($text/FieldName, '_LBL')"/>
```

Comment: is there any way to access data from xml and then ignore selected bits of it and then concat the bits you want with another string in xsl?

Comment: Xslt is about transforming the input xml file so obviously you are able to access basically all the information contained in the xml file you are transforming and more (e.g. additional external xml documents, external parameters if passed, etc.).